# ¿Cómo sumar varios input que ya traen funciones con JavaScript o Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gracias por leer. En mi proyecto necesito sumar una serie de inputs que ya traen datos, y estos datos son obtenidos de forma dinamica por medio de Jquery. El problema se presenta a la hora de sumar los input 'resultados'; por ejemplo: Tengo el **input 'A', 'B' y 'C'**... **El input 'A' es el resultado de las sumas de 'x' input**... **Al igual que el input 'B' que es el resultado de sumar input 'y' y restar el input 'z'**, entonces, ***necesito sumar el input 'A' + 'B' y mostrar el resultado global en el 'C'***. Mi proyecto es este:

```js
function multiplicara(){
a1 = document.getElementById("a").value;
r = a1*5;
  document.getElementById("aA").value = r;
}
function multiplicarb(){
a1 = document.getElementById("b").value;
r = a1*10;
  document.getElementById("bB").value = r;
}
function multiplicarc(){
a1 = document.getElementById("c").value;
r = a1*25;
  document.getElementById("cC").value = r;
}
function multiplicard(){
a1 = document.getElementById("d").value;
r = a1*50;
  document.getElementById("dD").value = r;
}
function multiplicare(){
a1 = document.getElementById("e").value;
r = a1*100;
  document.getElementById("eE").value = r;
}
function multiplicarf(){
a1 = document.getElementById("f").value;
r = a1*500;
  document.getElementById("fF").value = r;
}
function multiplicarA(){
a1 = document.getElementById("A").value;
r = a1*1000;
  document.getElementById("AA").value = r;
}
function multiplicarB(){
a1 = document.getElementById("B").value;
r = a1*2000;
  document.getElementById("BB").value = r;
}
function multiplicarC(){
a1 = document.getElementById("C").value;
r = a1*5000;
  document.getElementById("CC").value = r;
}
function multiplicarD(){
a1 = document.getElementById("D").value;
r = a1*10000;
  document.getElementById("DD").value = r;
}
function multiplicarE(){
a1 = document.getElementById("E").value;
r = a1*20000;
  document.getElementById("EE").value = r;
}
function multiplicarF(){
a1 = document.getElementById("F").value;
r = a1*50000;
  document.getElementById("FF").value = r;
}
function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.amt').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#totEfectivo').val(add);
   $('#finturno').val(add);
  };
function justNumbers(e)
        {
        var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
        if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
        return true;
         
        return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
        }
function resta() {
 var numero1 = document.getElementById('montovta').value;
 var numero2 = document.getElementById('montodevo').value;
 var resultado = parseInt(numero1) - parseInt(numero2);
 document.getElementById('totaltdc').value = resultado;
}
function sumados() {
 var aa = document.getElementById('totEfectivo').value;
 var bb = document.getElementById('totaltdc').value;
 var rr = parseInt(aa) + parseInt(bb);
 document.getElementById('finturno').value = rr;
}
function operacion() {
 var cc = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
 var dd = document.getElementById('vtas').value;
 var ee = document.getElementById('finturno').value;
 var rf = parseInt(cc) + parseInt(dd) - parseInt(ee);
 document.getElementById('diferencia').value = rf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<table align="center" width="40%">
     <tr align="center">
         <td><h1>REGISTRAR CIERRE DE CAJA</h1></td>
        </tr>
 </table><br />
    <table align="left" width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
         <td colspan="12"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;I. Conteo de Efectivo</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#000000">
        <td>Monedas de ¢5</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cinco" id="a" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢5" onchange="multiplicara(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢10</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diez" id="b" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢10" onchange="multiplicarb(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢25</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="veinticinco" id="c" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢25" onchange="multiplicarc(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢50</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cincuenta" id="d" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢50" onchange="multiplicard(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢100</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cien" id="e" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢100" onchange="multiplicare(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢500</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quinientos" id="f" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢500" onchange="multiplicarf(); suma();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot5" id="aA" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢5" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot10" id="bB" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢10" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot25" id="cC" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢25" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot50" id="dD" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢50" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot100" id="eE" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢100" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot500" id="fF" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢500" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#000000">
        <td>Billetes ¢1,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mil" id="A" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢1,000" onchange="multiplicarA(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢2,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="2mil" id="B" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢2,000" onchange="multiplicarB(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢5,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="5mil" id="C" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢5,000" onchange="multiplicarC(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢10,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="10mil" id="D" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢10,000" onchange="multiplicarD(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢20,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="20mil" id="E" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢20,000" onchange="multiplicarE(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢50,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="50mil" id="F" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢50,000" onchange="multiplicarF(); suma();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot1" id="AA" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢1,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot2" id="BB" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢2,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot5" id="CC" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢5,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot10" id="DD" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢10,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot20" id="EE" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢20,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot50" id="FF" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢50,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="12">Total Efectivo:&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totEfectivo" id="totEfectivo" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" class="cierres" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>&nbsp;
    <table align="right" width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;II. Conteo de Datafóno</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Terminal ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="terminal" id="terminal" readonly="readonly" value="00121509" title="ID del terminal, Banco Nacional" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Lote #:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lote" id="lote" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" placeholder="Número de Lote (cierre)" title="Número de Lote (cierre)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Número de Ventas:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ventanum" id="ventanum" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Número de Ventas" title="Número de Ventas" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Monto Ventas ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quitar" name="montovta" id="montovta" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Total de Ventas" title="Total de Ventas" value="0" onchange="resta();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Número de Devoluciones:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="devonum" id="devonum" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Número de Devoluciones" title="Número de Devoluciones" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Monto Devoluciones ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quitar" name="montodevo" id="montodevo" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Total de Devoluciones" title="Total de Devoluciones" value="0" onchange="resta();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Fecha de Transacción:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" title="Fecha de Transacción" readonly="readonly" value="<?php $fecha = date("d/m/Y"); echo $fecha; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">Total Venta Tarjetas&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totaltdc" id="totaltdc" title="Total Ventas Tarjeta" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" class="cierres" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>&nbsp;
    <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="45%">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;III. Datos del turno</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Turno en el que reporta el Cierre:</td>
        <td><select name="turno" title="Seleccione el Turno"><option value="">Seleccione...</option><option value="AM">AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Hora:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hora" title="Hora Actual" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Costa_Rica'); $now = date("H:i:s"); echo $now; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Inicio de Caja ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="inicio" id="inicio" title="Monto al iniciar jornada" value="25000" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="6" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Ventas Facturadas en Mónica ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vtas" id="vtas" value="0" title="Monto vendido en Mónica" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="6" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Conteo total Fin de Turno ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="finturno" id="finturno" value="0" title="Conteo total Fin de Turno" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Diferencia ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="0" title="Sobrante o Faltante" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Como verán el código es un poco repetitivo, la verdad es debido a que necesito repetir estas funciones y también porque soy novato. Si ejecutan el ejemplo verán que hay el input `<input type="text" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="0" title="Sobrante o Faltante" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" />` me dice que **no es un número** (NaN) a la hora de ir llenando los demás input.

De antemano agradezco las respuestas que puedan surgir.

Comment: Es curioso que acá al publicar el código si me hace la función de sumar 'Inicio de caja' + 'ventas facturadas' - 'conteo total' (supongo que será el caché o las cookies del browser). Pero en sí el input 'conteo total' es el resultado de sumar 'total efectivo' + 'total venta tarjeta' y el valor de la venta de tarjetas lo ignora por completo...

Comment: Te recomendaría que para facilitar tu proceso de depuración y el de los demás (nosotros) que quieren ayudarte colocar valores referenciales lo más precisos posibles a tus inputs y variables. Es muy dificil seguir un proceso cuando lees que tienes muchos id de inputs que se parecen (a, aA, AA) y las variables casi no indican nada en el proceso (r, aa, ff)

Comment: Otra cosa cuando postees código trata que sea facil de probar. Cuestión de que nosotros copiemos el código y podamos inmediatamente probarlo. Con  el formulario con esa cantidad de readonly="readonly" que tienes no se puede ingresar ningún valor y esto no permite que sepamos rapidamente porque no estan sumando esos inputs ya que no podemos "testear" el código con algunas "entradas" de datos

Comment: Huskie, muy valido tu punto. Los input 'readonly' estan diseñados para no tener que modificarlos, pues son input 'resultantes' que sólo obtendrán el resultado de esa operación. Gracias por tus comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí todo funciona bien, el único caso en el que sale NAN es cuando el input está vacío y eso lo puedes solucionar de la siguinte manera:

```
    function operacion() {
        var cc = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
        var dd = document.getElementById('vtas').value;
        if(cc==null || cc=="") cc = 0;
        if(dd==null || dd=="") dd = 0;
        var ee = document.getElementById('finturno').value;
        var rf = parseInt(cc) + parseInt(dd) - parseInt(ee);
        document.getElementById('diferencia').value = rf;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Iñigo, funciono, el problema del NaN era porque al inicio el input no tenia value. Al agregar el '0' ya pasa a ser un número. Te agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Aclarado el punto mayor de arriba sólo me queda un detalle. Hay una suma que no se completa y no sé porqué. Vean el fragmento de mi código:

```html
<table align="left" width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
         <td colspan="12"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;I. Conteo de Efectivo</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#000000">
        <td>Monedas de ¢5</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cinco" id="a" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢5" onchange="multiplicara(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢10</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diez" id="b" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢10" onchange="multiplicarb(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢25</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="veinticinco" id="c" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢25" onchange="multiplicarc(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢50</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cincuenta" id="d" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢50" onchange="multiplicard(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢100</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cien" id="e" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢100" onchange="multiplicare(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Monedas de ¢500</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quinientos" id="f" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Monedas de ¢500" onchange="multiplicarf(); suma();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot5" id="aA" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢5" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot10" id="bB" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢10" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot25" id="cC" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢25" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot50" id="dD" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢50" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot100" id="eE" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢100" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot500" id="fF" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢500" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bordercolor="#000000">
        <td>Billetes ¢1,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mil" id="A" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢1,000" onchange="multiplicarA(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢2,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="2mil" id="B" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢2,000" onchange="multiplicarB(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢5,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="5mil" id="C" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢5,000" onchange="multiplicarC(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢10,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="10mil" id="D" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢10,000" onchange="multiplicarD(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢20,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="20mil" id="E" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢20,000" onchange="multiplicarE(); suma();" /></td>
        <td>Billetes ¢50,000</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="50mil" id="F" maxlength="2" size="1" title="Billetes de ¢50,000" onchange="multiplicarF(); suma();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot1" id="AA" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢1,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot2" id="BB" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢2,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot5" id="CC" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢5,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot10" id="DD" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢10,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot20" id="EE" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢20,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">¢<input type="text" name="tot50" id="FF" class="amt" size="5" title="Total ¢50,000" value="0" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="12">Total Efectivo:&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totEfectivo" id="totEfectivo" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

En donde el input 'resultante' es este:

```
<td colspan="12">Total Efectivo:&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totEfectivo" id="totEfectivo" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
```

Luego, el siguiente bloque, donde deseo sumar el input 'resultante' con el anterior es este:

```html
<table align="right" width="45%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;II. Conteo de Datafóno</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Terminal ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="terminal" id="terminal" readonly="readonly" value="00121509" title="ID del terminal, Banco Nacional" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Lote #:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lote" id="lote" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" placeholder="Número de Lote (cierre)" title="Número de Lote (cierre)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Número de Ventas:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ventanum" id="ventanum" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Número de Ventas" title="Número de Ventas" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Monto Ventas ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quitar" name="montovta" id="montovta" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Total de Ventas" title="Total de Ventas" value="0" onchange="resta();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Número de Devoluciones:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="devonum" id="devonum" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Número de Devoluciones" title="Número de Devoluciones" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Monto Devoluciones ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quitar" name="montodevo" id="montodevo" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Total de Devoluciones" title="Total de Devoluciones" value="0" onchange="resta();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Fecha de Transacción:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" title="Fecha de Transacción" readonly="readonly" value="<?php $fecha = date("d/m/Y"); echo $fecha; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">Total Venta Tarjetas&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totaltdc" id="totaltdc" title="Total Ventas Tarjeta" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

En donde el input 'resultante' de este bloque es este:

```
<td colspan="2">Total Venta Tarjetas&nbsp;<b style="font-size:200%;">¢</b><input type="text" name="totaltdc" id="totaltdc" title="Total Ventas Tarjeta" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93; font-size:200%;" size="5" onchange="sumados();" /></td>
```

Ahora, al sumar estos dos input, el resultado deseo que lo reciba en este bloque:

```html
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="45%">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>&nbsp;III. Datos del turno</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Turno en el que reporta el Cierre:</td>
        <td><select name="turno" title="Seleccione el Turno"><option value="">Seleccione...</option><option value="AM">AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Hora:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hora" title="Hora Actual" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Costa_Rica'); $now = date("H:i:s"); echo $now; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Inicio de Caja ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="iniciar" id="iniciar" title="Monto al iniciar jornada" value="25000" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="6" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Ventas Facturadas en Mónica ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vtas" id="vtas" value="0" title="Monto vendido en Mónica" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" maxlength="6" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Conteo total Fin de Turno ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="finturno" id="finturno" value="0" title="Conteo total Fin de Turno" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" onchange="operacion();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Diferencia ¢:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="0" title="Sobrante o Faltante" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

En concreto, deseo que el valor lo reciba este input:

```
<td><input type="text" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="0" title="Sobrante o Faltante" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#F93;" /></td>
```

El código JS que realiza la suma es este:

```js
function sumados() {
 var aa = document.getElementById('totEfectivo').value;
 var bb = document.getElementById('totaltdc').value;
 var rr = parseInt(aa) + parseInt(bb);
 document.getElementById('finturno').value = rr;
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando la función se dispara, sólo toma el valor del resultante input name="totEfectivo". Al ingresar datos en el otro bloque, para obtener el dato del input name="totaltdc" lo ignora por completo.

La función se dispara, pero no toma en cuenta el último valor de la suma, por ende el resultado de 'totEfectivo' lo coloca en el input destino name="diferencia"

Alguna ayuda?

Gracias.